# Issues installing tabulizer in R on Mac OS13 and R 4.4

Tags: r, rjava, tabulizer

I'm having many issues installing tabulizer in R 4.4 on my Mac OS13. I've reproduced the error message below. I've tried every other suggestion on stack and nothing seems to do the trick. I've verified the rJava is installed. Thanks for any help!

> remotes::install_github(c("ropensci/tabulizerjars", "ropensci/tabulizer"))
> Downloading GitHub repo ropensci/tabulizerjars@HEAD
> ── R CMD build ────────────────────────────────────────────
> ✔  checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/wn/fx85qp5d0g9fmz3x3fff93mh0000gn/T/Rtmp5AWuHG/remotes538f6671afb/ropensci-tabulizerjars-d1924e0/DESCRIPTION’ ...
> ─  preparing ‘tabulizerjars’:
> ✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
> ─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
> ─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
> ─  building ‘tabulizerjars_1.0.1.tar.gz’

- installing *source* package ‘tabulizerjars’ ...
  ** using staged installation
  ** R
  ** inst
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  ** help
  *** installing help indices
  ** building package indices
  ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
  Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tabulizerjars’:
  .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tabulizerjars', details:
  call: NULL
  error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(jvm, FALSE)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib':
  dlopen(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib, 0x000A): tried: '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))
  Error: loading failed
  Execution halted
  ERROR: loading failed
- removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/tabulizerjars’
  Downloading GitHub repo ropensci/tabulizer@HEAD
  Downloading GitHub repo ropensci/tabulizerjars@HEAD
  ── R CMD build ────────────────────────────────────────────
  ✔  checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/wn/fx85qp5d0g9fmz3x3fff93mh0000gn/T/Rtmp5AWuHG/remotes538f5c53530/ropensci-tabulizerjars-d1924e0/DESCRIPTION’ ...
  ─  preparing ‘tabulizerjars’:
  ✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information
  ─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
  ─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
  ─  building ‘tabulizerjars_1.0.1.tar.gz’
- installing *source* package ‘tabulizerjars’ ...
  ** using staged installation
  ** R
  ** inst
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  ** help
  *** installing help indices
  ** building package indices
  ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
  Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tabulizerjars’:
  .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tabulizerjars', details:
  call: NULL
  error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(jvm, FALSE)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib':
  dlopen(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib, 0x000A): tried: '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))
  Error: loading failed
  Execution halted
  ERROR: loading failed
- removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/tabulizerjars’
  Downloading GitHub repo ropensci/tabulizerjars@HEAD
  Skipping tabulizerjars, it is already being installed
  ── R CMD build ────────────────────────────────────────────
  ✔  checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/wn/fx85qp5d0g9fmz3x3fff93mh0000gn/T/Rtmp5AWuHG/remotes538f64daab72/ropensci-tabulizer-08e3d76/DESCRIPTION’ ...
  ─  preparing ‘tabulizer’:
  ✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
  ─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
  ─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
  Removed empty directory ‘tabulizer/docs’
  ─  building ‘tabulizer_0.2.3.tar.gz’

ERROR: dependency ‘tabulizerjars’ is not available for package ‘tabulizer’

- removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/tabulizer’
  Warning messages:
  1: In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/wn/fx85qp5d0g9fmz3x3fff93mh0000gn/T//Rtmp5AWuHG/file538f5b1c5805/tabulizerjars_1.0.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
  2: In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/wn/fx85qp5d0g9fmz3x3fff93mh0000gn/T//Rtmp5AWuHG/file538f5626e545/tabulizerjars_1.0.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
  3: In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/wn/fx85qp5d0g9fmz3x3fff93mh0000gn/T//Rtmp5AWuHG/file538f3cd1f86a/tabulizer_0.2.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: FYI R is currently at version `4.2.2`. I don't think `R 4.4` exists yet.

Comment: Can you share a bit more information about what you've tried? It would also be useful to know what version of Java you have installed (often requires manual installation to get the right version). Are you able to install rJava?